# Issue with integral for surface area of revolution.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Currently doing a high school maths investigation about using calculus for solids of revolution. We are looking at the surface area of polynomials revolved around the y-axis. We have been given the formula: SA=2π∫ g(y)√(1+[g^'(y)]^2 )dy. All of our curves must therefore be in terms of y.

My calculator cannot solve this formula for the curve x=([125/10]^(1/3)*(y)^(1/3))+5, and a similar equation but the powers were 1/4. It would only work for a degree of 1/2.

My only though is that the formula relates to the second derivative of the equations, as for any curve in terms of y with a degree less then 1/2, d^2x/dy^2 is undefined at the lower bound of the integral 0. It will work if this is 0.1, however I need to discuss why this is happening.

I'm not sure how this may relate to the formula and can't find any other reason as to why I can only solve one of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To make the problem more general, you have
$$g(y)=a y^{\frac 13}+b\implies g'(y)=\frac{a}{3 y^{2/3}}$$
$$g(y)\sqrt{1+\big[g'(y)\big]^2}=\left(a y^{\frac 13}+b\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{9 y^{4/3}}} $$ With $a>0$, the series expansion of the integrand is
$$\frac{a b}{3 y^{2/3}}+\frac{a^2}{3 y^{1/3}}+\frac{3 b y^{2/3}}{2 a}+\frac{3
   y}{2}+O\left(y^{2}\right)$$ which does not make any problem close to $0$ if this is the lower bound.

Now, concerning the integration, you face a problem where appear elliptic integrals.

Just wait a little to hear about them.

Meanwhile, if the integration range is small, try a series solution.